# How to set run multiple controller functions in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently working on boiler plate code of mean.io and implementing passwordresetemail to it. When ever user asks for password reset with email as parameter, I create a salt(resetid) and send him an email having that salt as reset link.

I have user's email in the req but want to append other information of the user(user._id) before it enters into actual createemail controller function. I want following function(userbyemail) to be run before it goes into createResetPasswordEmailLink

```
/**
 * Find user by email
 */
exports.userByEmail = function(req, res, next, email) {
    User
        .findOne({
            email: email
        })
        .exec(function(err, user) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (!user) return next(new Error('Failed to load User with email ' + email));
            req.user = user;
            next();
        });
};

exports.createResetPasswordEmailLink = function(req, res) {

    var resetPassword = new ResetPassword(req.body);
    resetPassword.resetId = new User().makeSalt();
    **resetPassword.user = req.user._id;  // currently req.user is null**

    console.log(resetPassword.userId);
    resetPassword.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            // handle error
        }
        res.status(200);
        return res.redirect('/');
    });
};
```

Following is my resetPassword schema

```
var ResetPasswordSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    resetId: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

My routes is defined as follows

```
// Setting up the users resetpasswordlink
app.route('/createresetpasswordemaillink')
    .post(users.createResetPasswordEmailLink);
```

Comment: I think `exports.userByEmail` should rather be a model method than a controller. Also you should not alter the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this issue with app.params. App.params is exactly defined for this kind of usage.

I added

```
// Setting up the userId param
app.param('email', users.userByEmail);
```

to my routes and it automatically executed this function before the req is passed on to regular controllers.

From the documentation, App.param is defined as

*app.param([name], callback)
Map logic to route parameters. For example when :user is present in a route path you may map user loading logic to automatically provide req.user to the route, or perform validations on the parameter input.*